# Phaser: Z-ordering not working

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a tile-based, top-down-ish game using phaser, and I'm having issues getting the z order working.

I've put both my objects and player into one spawner class, with the code as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.mapFile.objects.length; i++) {
  if (this.mapFile.objects[i] === CONST.TILE.OBJECT.WALL) {
    var gridTile = this.grid.getTileAtIndex(i);
    if (gridTile.tileBaseObj) {
      var wall = new Wall(this.game, gridTile.x, gridTile.y, null, gridTile);
      gridTile.tileBaseObj.z = 2;
      this.group.add(gridTile.tileBaseObj);
    }
  }
  else if (this.mapFile.objects[i] === CONST.TILE.OBJECT.START) {        
    var gridTile = this.grid.getTileAtIndex(i);
    if (gridTile.tileBaseObj) {
      var startObj = new FloorObject(this.game, 'gridSampleStartPoint', gridTile, null);
      gridTile.tileBaseObj.z = 1;
      this.group.add(gridTile.tileBaseObj);
    }
  }
}

this.player = new Player(this.game, 'prohyasIdle', this.playerStartTile);
this.player.z = 2;
```

The secondary object, with the `z` of 1, is the player start tile, where the player, with a `z` of 2, spawns.

Unfortunately, the player appears behind the tile.

Going with the rather unhelpful sample from phaser [here](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/groups/depth-sort), it seems as if there's a built-in option to sort, via the objects' and the player's `y` value, but that example physically moves the player, whereas in my game I use tweens to snap the player to the tiles.

- Manually setting the player's `z` to 100 doesn't work. Notably, removing the player and an object from any group and setting the former's `z` to 100, and the latter to 0, still makes the object come out on top, if it is created / drawn later. Does this mean there is no (easy) Z-ordering in Phaser?
- Sorting it by `y` doesn't solve the problem, and even introduces another problem: moving the character downwards places it behind the floor tile, when it should be on top.
- Sorting it by `z` instead also does nothing.

While I'd like to use the three groups approach, and simply move the sprites between groups, I'm afraid that solution might prove cumbersome when there could be hundreds of sprites that need moving.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Do you always need `player` to be on top (i.e. above everything else)? If that's the case, I'd suggest creating another group after you've created your tiles, then adding your player to that. It's been a while since I've done much with Phaser, but I'm pretty sure that tweens tend to take sprites completely out of the ordering flow.

Comment: @indextwo, no, actually, in most cases the tile below the player might have bits sticking out from, say, a lamp post, or a stop sign. That should be able to 'cover' the `player`.

Comment: So, just to be clear: you've got a ground tile layer; then the player; then a layer of 'obstacles' (for lack of a better word)? I would be tempted to still arrange them into groups. The other thing to note is that your `gridTile.tileBaseObj.z` can be `2`, which is the same as your player. If they're in the same group, they can't have the same `z` value. Also: have you tried setting `depth` instead of `z`? I've got a feeling the latter is read-only.